# Maximum height of textarea to 300px (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't make a maximum height limit to 300px of textarea which height varies.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3gp66Lsr/)

```
function init () {
var text = document.getElementById('text');
function resize () {
text.style.height = 'auto';
text.style.height = text.scrollHeight+'px';
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can do this with css

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simply a matter of checking the height prior to resizing.  If you would like to eliminate scrollbar flicker consider setting overlflow-y to hidden until 300:

```
function resize () {

    var height = text.scrollHeight <= 300 ? text.scrollHeight : 300;
    text.style.height = height+'px';

}
```

fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/vtr8kvkx/2/

Comment: Thanks. Awesome reply